# UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus on TextView

Tags: swift, xctest, xcode7-beta6

I'm facing a problem with 'Textview' type field. I am unable to enter text in `FeedbackTextView` field.

```
let FeedbackTextView = app.staticTexts["Feedback Textview"]

FeedbackTextView.tap()

FeedbackTextView.typeText("This is test feedback")
```

Following error is displayed when above code is executed.

> UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard
>   focus. Element:

Comment: To make your code easier to read, you should begin instance variables with a lowercase letter (`feedbackTextView`)

Comment: Does this code compile? `FeedbackTextView` would be optional, but I don't see you unwrapping the optional.

Comment: Code compile successfully. However, tap() command on feedbackTextView is executed successfully. When "typeText" function is executed then it doesn't write anything in field and following error is thrown.

UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Element:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode UI Testing Error keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115375/xcode-ui-testing-error-keyboard)

Answer (score 25):

I faced this same problem with Xcode 7.0.1 and was able to resolve it by turning off the connected hardware keyboard in the simulator settings. Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard (uncheck this). The hardware keyboard was causing issues when calling tap() on more than one TextField in a given view. This bug has been reported, hopefully it will be resolved in a future release.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is the difference between staticTexts, textFields and secureTextFields. I ran into this issue again when attempting to access a secure text field by calling textFields on the XCUIApplication instead of secureTextFields. Xcode threw a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue may be to do with the simulator. iOS 9.0 and 9.1 work but seems to be broken on 9.2 and 9.3. There is a radar open http://www.openradar.me/23899170

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue this morning and adding `app.typeText("\n")`after every UITextField fixed it