# Xcode UI Testing Error keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app.buttons[@"Committee"] tap];
[app.buttons[@"Login"] tap];
[app.buttons[@"Add Presenter"] tap];

XCUIElement *nameTextField = app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.textFields[@"Name"]/*[[".scrollViews.textFields[@\"Name\"]",".textFields[@\"Name\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/;
[nameTextField tap];
[nameTextField typeText:@"A"];

XCUIElement *topicTextField = app/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.textFields[@"Topic"]/*[[".scrollViews.textFields[@\"Topic\"]",".textFields[@\"Topic\"]"],[[[-1,1],[-1,0]]],[0]]@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/;
[topicTextField tap];
[topicTextField tap];
```

my error is when run the UI test I receive UI Testing Failure

> Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.

Attributes: TextField however the test above passed I have attached a screenshot of what exactly failing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsUiv.png)

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32184837/ui-testing-failure-neither-element-nor-any-descendant-has-keyboard-focus-on-se

Answer (score 2):

I faced this same problem with Xcode 7.0.1 and was able to resolve it by turning off the connected hardware keyboard in the simulator settings. Hardware -> Keyboard -> Connect Hardware Keyboard (uncheck this). 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604630/ui-testing-failure-neither-element-nor-any-descendant-has-keyboard-focus-on-te)

Comment: is there a way to disable it automatically? It will be enabled with every run

Answer (score 0):

Works for me for native screens:

```
extension XCUIElement {
    func typeTextAlt(_ text: String) {
        // Solution for `Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus.`
        if !(self.value(forKey: "hasKeyboardFocus") as? Bool ?? false) {
            XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
            XCUIApplication().activate()
        }
        self.typeText(text)
    }
}
```