# Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus

Tags: ios, swift, ui-testing, xcode-ui-testing

i'm new im xcode-ui and have one problem.

```
Assertion Failure: UI Testing Failure - Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Element:
Attributes: Other 0x7f8c1cb703d0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 167.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'XXXXXXX'
Element subtree:
 →Other 0x7f8c1cb703d0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 167.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'XXXXXXX'
Path to element:
 →Application 0x7f8c1cb71870: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: 'A'
  ↳Window 0x7f8c1cb78850: Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
   ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb77470: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
    ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb68100: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}
     ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb62260: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, }}
      ↳Other 0x7f8c1cd44e20: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0,}}
       ↳Other 0x7f8c1cd45580: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0,}}
        ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb63040: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0,}}
         ↳ScrollView 0x7f8c1cb60e80: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, 
          ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb73fc0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 64.0}, {375.0}}
           ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb73930: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 124.0}, 
            ↳Other 0x7f8c1cb703d0: traits: 8589934592,  label: 'XXXXXXXX'
Query chain:
 →Find: Target Application 0x7f8c19c46190
  Output: {
    Application 0x7f8c1cb71870: {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0, 667.0}}, label: 'App'
  }
  ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type ScrollView
    Output: {
      ScrollView 0x7f8c1cb60e80: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {375.0,}}
    }
    ↪︎Find: Descendants matching type Other
      Output: {
        Other 0x7f8c1cb7bb90: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 124.0}, {375.0, 
        Other 0x7f8c1cc55950: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 168.0}, {375.0, 
        Other 0x7f8c1cc55270: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 124.0}, {375.0, 
        Other 0x7f8c1cb74650: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 124.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'XXXXXXXX'
        Other 0x7f8c1cb703d0: traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 167.0}, {375.0, 44.0}}, label: 'XXXXXXXX'
```

I recorded a test an play it, but it did work. Here the code:

```
let elementsQuery = app.scrollViews.otherElements
let a = elementsQuery.otherElements["XXXXXXXXX"]
a.tap()
app.typeText("rerererdre")
let b = elementsQuery.otherElements["YYYYYYYYY"]
b.tap()
```

The test crash after it typed the text into the a field. a and b are two textfield in a scrollviews. I tried it with app.textFields["XXXXXXXXX"] but it didn't work.

Any ideas?
Cheers

The "Connect hardware keyboard" is off.

Comment: Recheck your text fields are in place and have `User Interaction Enabled` trait and `Accessibility` flags checked in Interface Builder. Where does text field have your `"XXXXXX"` string? In `Accessibility Identifier` property or somewhere other place?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode UI Testing Error keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115375/xcode-ui-testing-error-keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

Check the existence of the textfield 'b' maybe b is getting value null and with that null value you are calling tap() method.

try like this,

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
 let elementsQuery = app.scrollViews.otherElements
 if(elementsQuery.textFields["XXXXXXXX"].exists)
{
  let x = elementsQuery.textFields["XXXXXXXX"]
  x.tap()
}
if(elementsQuery.textFields["YYYYYYYY"].exists)
{
  let y = elementsQuery.textFields["YYYYYYYY"]
  y.tap()
}
```

Put a breakpoint and check whether it exists or not.