# SwiftUI TextEditor UI Testing Failure for typeText method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing

"typeText" method is working for 'TextField' element but not working for the 'TextEditor' element in the Xcode UI Tests. Connecting Hardware Keyboard options (enable/disable) were tried and no success. Any workarounds?

> Failed to synthesize event: Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus. Event dispatch snapshot: TextView, identifier: 'content'

```
let nameTextField = app.textFields["name"]
nameTextField.tap()
nameTextField.typeText("Test Name") // Working 

let contentTextEditor = app.textViews["content"]
contentTextEditor.tap() // It successfully makes the cursor focus on the TextEditor element 
contentTextEditor.typeText("Test Content") // Here is the error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode UI Testing Error keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115375/xcode-ui-testing-error-keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try pasting instead?

```
let contentTextEditor = app.textViews["content"]
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string = "Test Content"
contentTextEditor.doubleTap()
app.menuItems.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap() // This is the ugly, but correct way to hit the paste button
XCTAssertEqual(contentTextEditor.value as? String, "Test Content")
```

Comment: This still seems to be the solution as of iOS 14.2.